# IIS UrlRewrite RewriteMap with HTTP Host condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

How can I use two different RewriteMaps based on the HTTP-Host to achieve something like the following?

**www.myfoo.com/test** should be rewritten to **/foo/test.aspx**
and
**www.mybar.com/test** should be rewritten to **/bar/test.aspx**

So far I've found http://forums.iis.net/t/1177509.aspx/1 and adapted it to my needs:

```
<rule name="Rewrite rule1 for rewritemapFoo">
 <match url=".*"/>
 <conditions>
   <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.myfoo\.com$" />
   <add input="{URL}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^.+\.((axd)|(js)|(xaml))$" ignoreCase="true" negate="true"/>
   <add input="{rewritemapFoo:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)"/>
 </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false"/>
</rule>

<rule name="Rewrite rule1 for rewritemapBar">
 <match url=".*"/>
 <conditions>
   <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.mybar\.com$" />
   <add input="{URL}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^.+\.((axd)|(js)|(xaml))$" ignoreCase="true" negate="true"/>
   <add input="{rewritemapBar:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)"/>
 </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false"/>
</rule>


...

 <rewriteMap name="rewritemapFoo">
   <add key="/test" value="/foo/test.aspx"/>
 </rewriteMap>
 <rewriteMap name="rewritemapBar">
   <add key="/test" value="/bar/test.aspx"/>
 </rewriteMap>
```

Unfortunately, I'll only get a 404 response upon calling www.myfoo.com/test and www.mybar.com/test. Can anyone point out, what I'm missing?

Comment: Do you really need a RewriteMap? you could simply reuse whatever is in the HTTP_HOST

Comment: Hey @citronas, I have the exact same issue, wondering if you ever found a solution to this?

Comment: @Jono: I posted my code into a new answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jono: Yes. This is the code thats work with conditions and `{HTTP_HOST}`

```
<rule name="Rewrite rule1 for ABC">
  <match url=".*"/>
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.abc\.de$"/>
    <add input="{URL}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^.+\.((axd)|(js)|(xaml))$" ignoreCase="true" negate="true"/>
    <add input="{ABC:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)"/>
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false"/>
</rule>
<rule name="Rewrite rule2 for ABC">
  <match url=".*"/>
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^abc\.de$"/>
    <add input="{URL}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^.+\.((axd)|(js)|(xaml))$" ignoreCase="true" negate="true"/>
    <add input="{ABC:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)"/>
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false"/>
</rule>
<rule name="Rewrite rule1 for XYZ">
  <match url=".*"/>
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.xyz\.de$"/>
    <add input="{URL}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^.+\.((axd)|(js)|(xaml))$" ignoreCase="true" negate="true"/>
    <add input="{XYZ:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)"/>
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false"/>
</rule>
<rule name="Rewrite rule2 for XYZ">
  <match url=".*"/>
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^xyz\.de$"/>
    <add input="{URL}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^.+\.((axd)|(js)|(xaml))$" ignoreCase="true" negate="true"/>
    <add input="{XYZ:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)"/>
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false"/>
</rule>


<rewriteMap name="ABC">
  <add key="/" value="/aa/start.aspx"/>
  <add key="/foo" value="/aa/foo.aspx"/>
</rewriteMap>
<rewriteMap name="XYZ">
  <add key="/" value="/bb/start.aspx"/>
  <add key="/foo" value="/bb/foo.aspx"/>
</rewriteMap>
```

Comment: Thanks @citronas!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Conditions](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#Rule_conditions) for this. In conditions you have access to [server variables](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#UsingServerVars) which contains a key 'HTTP_HOST' with the value for host name.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying. Would you mind telling me, what I'm doing wrong in my case?

Comment: @citronas why do you have --> at the end of host condition for both the rules?

Comment: Sorry, anonymization issues. I don't have them in my code and edited it accordingly.

Comment: @citronas try ignoreCase="true" for host condition as well as it is possible that host name is converted to all uppercase. Also you are using maps so I assume that you have a corresponding key defined in the map for the incoming url.

Comment: No success with ignoreCase="true". The maps are also part of the code sample